# laravel sync and detach won't work on deleting all instances

Tags: php, laravel, synchronization, detach

I'm working on a project where users can work on multiple projects and projects can have multiple users working on it.
With this project I am using the sync method to add and delete instances in the pivot table.
Whenever I am using sync with an empty array or detach to delete all instances that have a certain project id, it doesn't work and the instances keep existing.

While the sync with parameters work to add data to the database I find it very strange that deleting wont work.
Same with a sync on only one instance while there are more instances in the database, it will delete the other instances and keep the one.

My function:

```
public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request)
        {
            if($request->get('contribute'))
            {
                foreach($request->get('contribute') as $k => $contribute)
                {
                    if($contribute == 1)
                    {
                        $this->project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
                        $keys[] = $k;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isset($keys))
            {
                $this->project->users()->sync($keys);
            }
            else
            {
```

> $this->project->users()->detach();

```
            }

            $this->project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
            $this->project->fill($request->input())->save();

            return redirect('project');
        }
```

Comment: same if I use $this->project->users()->sync(array(); on the quoted spot.

Comment: I found the problem, $this->project was empty because I declared it in the foreach.